# "Failed to execute rule" - Civirules error, How to solve?

Tags: email, civirules, message-templates, tags

I have a set of civirules in places, when a contact is tagged it should send a welcome email. But I am keep receiving the following error message in log and welcome email is not sent. It happens for new & existing contacts. Anyone has a clue what is it? How to fix it please? Thanks.

Log in Drupal:

```
Civirules api action exception: Mandatory key(s) missing from params array: source_contact_id. API call: Email.send with params: from_name="Email from", from_email="abc@example.com", template_id="108", location_type_id="1", alternative_receiver_address="test@me.com", cc="", bcc="", file_on_case="", contact_id="8949", extra_data="Array"
```

Log in Civirules Logger:

```
    Array
(
    [line] => 77
    [file] => /home/webadmin/public_html/cmm/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/org.civicoop.civirules-master/CRM/CivirulesActions/Generic/Api.php
    [exception_message] => Civirules api action exception: Error sending e-mail to Katie Lost  . API call: Email.send with params: from_name="from name", from_email="abc@example.com", template_id="108", location_type_id="", alternative_receiver_address="", cc="", bcc="", file_on_case="", contact_id="9688", extra_data="Array"
    [rule_title] => Welcome Emails Workflow
    [original_error] => Error on {file} (Line {line})

{exception_message}
    [reason] => Failed to execute rule
)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. I tried this and works on my test sites. Can you usually send anything from the 'from' email address you are using for the rule?

Comment: Seems it’s an issue with msgtemplateblocker extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try after applying patch from [here](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/emailapi/-/merge_requests/10) may or may not be related!